# I want to create android app using backend has wamp server

Tags: android-studio, windows-7, wampserver

I want to create android application in android studio.
backend database i wamp server which is stored in a computer.
And the computer and my android devices are connect via wifi router.
How to i access the wamp server from my computer to android device please 
provide me a full solution to do this.

And I using windows 7 in computer my android device is dell venue 7 tablet and then i using wamp server 2.5 and anroid studio. finally my router is d-link.
my computer connected with router usign lan cable and my android device connect with router using wifi.
main thing is i want to use this app without internet.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You donot need internet to connect to the server in your pc. You can do it as follows:-

1. Connect your device to the computer with a usb cable
2. Use "10.10.0.2:portnumber/test.php" in your application which points to the server in your computer. test.php is your server code to access the database.

Comment: Its working in a emulator not in my android real device(Dell venue 7)